# matterllo - uWSGI/django & nginx 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, trello

I'm trying to set-up [matterllo](https://github.com/Lujeni/matterllo) on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

When I run the server manually via `python manage.py runserver`, without nginx, the hooks are creating with success.

But, when I try to put the things up via uWSGI behind nginx

LE: Same problem with gunicorn instead of nginx

```
delete trello hook :: result=[]
create trello hook :: callback=http://matterllo.x.com:8080/callback/1/ :: board=amazon-argila :: result=False
create trello hook :: callback=http://matterllo.x.com:com:8080/callback/2/ :: board=apiscrm :: result=False
create trello hook :: callback=http://matterllo.x.com:8080/callback/2/ :: board=apiscrm :: result=False
```

I found that "False" means 400 Bad Request

LE: Found that is a 403:

`create trello hook :: callback=https://matterllo.x.com:8443/callback/1/ :: board=amazon-argila :: result=URL (https://matterllo.x.com:8443/callback/1/) not reachable. Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403
create trello hook :: callback=https://matterllo.x.com:8443/callback/2/ :: board=apiscrm :: result=URL (https://matterllo.x.com:8443/callback/2/) not reachable. Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403
create trello hook :: callback=https://matterllo.x.com:8443/callback/2/ :: board=apiscrm :: result=URL (https://matterllo.x.com:8443/callback/2/) not reachable. Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403`

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name matterllo.x.com;

   location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/silviu/uwsgi/trello.sock;
   }
}
```

uwsgi ini config:

```
home = /home/silviu/matterllo/venv
chdir = /home/silviu/matterllo
wsgi-file = /home/silviu/matterllo/matterllo/wsgi.py
logger = file:/home/silviu/uwsgi/sites/trello.log
socket = /home/silviu/uwsgi/trello.sock
vacuum = true
master=true
chown-socket = silviu:www-data
chmod-socket = 666
uid = silviu
gid = www-data
die-on-term = true
module=run:app
```

/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown silviu:www-data /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /home/silviu/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And this is the create hook method, but I don't think the source of problem is it:

```
 def create_hook(self, callback_url, id_model, desc=None, token=None):
        """
        Creates a new webhook. Returns the WebHook object created.

        There seems to be some sort of bug that makes you unable to create a
        hook using httplib2, so I'm using urllib2 for that instead.
        """
        token = token or self.resource_owner_key

        if token is None:
            raise TokenError("You need to pass an auth token in to create a hook.")

        url = "https://trello.com/1/tokens/%s/webhooks/" % token
        data = {'callbackURL': callback_url, 'idModel': id_model,
                'description': desc}

        response = requests.post(url, data=data, auth=self.oauth)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            hook_id = response.json()['id']
            return WebHook(self, token, hook_id, desc, id_model, callback_url, True)
        else:
            return False
```

I don't have much experience with Python, but I think it's a problem with uWSGI.

Comment: Check the permission and the ownership of the socket file. 
If you run `sudo systemctl status uwsgi` or `journalctl -xe` what do you get?

Comment: @Peshmerge
I put on pastebin because the size of output:
https://pastebin.com/1nVWLtk5 
`journalctl -xe` shows only sshd logs, nothing about my problem.

Comment: This is so strange, it says that everything is set properly! 
Have you checked this? 
https://blog.anvileight.com/posts/how-to-fix-bad-request-400-in-django/

Comment: Yes, I have checked and the same problem. Now I output the content and ```create trello hook :: callback=https://matterllo.x.com:8443/callback/1/ :: board=amazon-argila :: result=URL (https://matterllo.x.com:8443/callback/1/) not reachable. Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403```